# android execute c program

Tags: java, android, c, ps

I have an android app which calls a C program. The C program while running returns some results via printf() which should be read in by the app.
The problem is when I run the C program in the adb shell it returns all printfs and terminates but when I call the C program in the app I don't receive all printf's and the program does not terminate, e.g.

```
./adb shell execution gives me             In app execution gives me 

  Start                                    Start
  1                                        1
  2                                        2
  3
  End
```

I checked with `ps` and the C program is still running
Here is how I execute the command in java:

```
public class RunCommands extends Thread {

private String cmd;

public RunCommands(String cmd) {
    this.cmd = cmd;
}

public void run() {

        ArrayList<String> list = null;

        try {
            Process result = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(result.getOutputStream());
            Scanner s = new Scanner(result.getInputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(this.cmd + "\n");
            dos.writeBytes("exit\n");
            dos.flush();

            String line;

            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                line = s.nextLine();
                list.add(line);
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
        }
}
```

And the call:

```
RunCommands rc = new RunCommands(getFileStreamPath(fileName).toString());
rc.start();
```

Comment: Are you executing `su`? If so thats most likely waiting for a password. If not is it some other command?

Comment: In the adb shell, can you run `<Your Program> | grep '\d+'`                 My suspicion is that the output is buffered when running from another program.

Comment: @FDinoff No I'm not running `su`, actually when the reading stops the C program is in a loop, I've already tried to decrease manually the number of times the loop is executed but it didn't change anything

Comment: With `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");`, you are executing `su`, not whatever is in `cmd`.

Comment: @Philippe sorry but the grep command does not exist -> grep: not found, I'm using Android 2.3.3 pls don't ask why I just needed to use this version!

Comment: @Sotirios Yes but then with `dos.writeBytes(this.cmd + "\n")` I'm executing cmd, the program is executed since I receive results from it, the problem is that it is not terminating or just stopping at some point!?

Comment: I think your C program fails. Check the exit code by doing `result.waitFor();`

Comment: Sorry, do `<Your C Program> | busybox grep '\d+'` and see if that command terminates at the same rate running the C program normally does, or if it hangs like calling it from your android app.

Comment: @Philippe I executed the command and the program does not give any output and does not terminate what does that mean?

Comment: That means the output buffer is not flushing for the C program.  You need to add this line in the C program: `fflush(stdout)`  whenever you use printf and want to read the output using another program.  Let me know if that works.

Comment: @Philippe I've tried to add `fflush(stdout)` but it didn't change anything the program still does not terminate